# How to deploy a resource in a secondary location in an Azure Resource Manager Template when it is unavailable in the primary location?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM template that is used to create resources in the location of a given Resource Group. Here is how I can deploy a SignalR service:

```
    {
        "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
        "name": "[variables('signalRName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.SignalRService/signalR",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": {},
        "sku": {
            "name": "Free_F1",
            "tier": "Free"
        },
        "properties": { }
   }
```

Being in Canada, I have access to two locations: `Canada East` and `Canada Central`. However SignalR that is not available in `Canada Central` yet but it is in `Canada East`:

> ew-AzResourceGroupDeployment: 11:40:32 AM - Error:
> Code=LocationNotAvailableForResourceType; Message=The provided
> location 'canadacentral' is not available for resource type
> 'Microsoft.SignalRService/SignalR'. List of available regions for the
> resource type is
> 'eastus,westus,southeastasia,westeurope,westus2,eastus2,northeurope,australiaeast,canadaeast,centralus,japaneast,uksouth,southcentralus,brazilsouth,francecentral,koreacentral'.

**Question**

What can I do to deploy the resource unavailable in the primary location into some secondary / fallback location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to achieve it at the expense of few tweaks. First, I have to specify myself a secondary location parameter in my parameters file.

For instance, in the following parameters file, I specified `Canada Central` as a primary location and `Canada East` as a secondary location:

```
    {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {
            "primaryLocation": {
                "value": "Canada Central"
            },
            "secondaryLocation": {
                "value": "Canada East"
            }
            ...
        }
    }
```

This parameter is defined in my deploy template file:

```
    {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {
            "primaryLocation": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 3,
                "maxLength": 32
            }
            "secondaryLocation": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 3,
                "maxLength": 32
            }
        }
        ... }
```

Then I found out about the [providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#providers) statement. This statement returns [the list of locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#return-value-2) available of a given resource type.

So I updated the `location` property to look for the resource group's location in the list of locations available for SignalR. [If](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-logical#if) it is [contained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-array#contains) in the list, then I use resource group's location. Otherwise, I use the secondary location provided.

```
    {
        "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
        "name": "[variables('signalRName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.SignalRService/signalR",
        "location": "[if(contains(providers('Microsoft.SignalRService', 'signalR').locations, parameters('primaryLocation')), parameters('primaryLocation'), parameters('secondaryLocation'))]",
        "tags": {},
        "sku": {
            "name": "Free_F1",
            "tier": "Free"
        },
        "properties": { }
    }
```

**Note**

I can't use `resourceGroup().location` because it does not return the location in the same format as `providers('Microsoft.SignalRService', 'signalR').locations`. The first one will return something like `canadaeast` whereas the second returns `Canada East`.

Comment: well, this is pretty much my first answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, you have to either know this beforehand or just handle the failure outside of the arm template and redeploy into another region. most of the services offer an api endpoint to figure out which locations are supported